# Get entire config group with scopeConfig

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml

Currently when I want to get an entire admin page worth of module configuration, i.e. a `<section>` or `<group>`, I just end up doing something like:

```
$emailOnSuccess = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('module/group/field_name',
        'website');
$emailOnFailure = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('module/group/field_name',
        'website');
$runFrequency = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('module/group/field_name',
        'website');
```

etc. etc.

This feels wrong, but I haven't found any way to get an entire config group with `scopeConfig`. Is there a way to do this?

P.S. `scopeConfig` is injected thus:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context)
{
    $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean to get all system config field values at once you could pass `null` as first parameter like:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue(null, 'website');
```

similarly to obtain specific module section or group configs:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('section_name', 'website');
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('section_name/group_name', 'website');
```

this will give you whole config values in array.

Comment: perfect answer!!! made my day +1 :)